# What causes a compiled library to store its build command internally?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, shared-libraries, static-libraries

Sometimes when I build a package from source, the resulting binaries seem to contain a reference to the build flags I'm using.

The example I'm working with is the fftw library.  Here's how to download and build it.

FWIW, these lines take about ~30 seconds to execute, so give it a try.

```bash
cd /tmp
wget http://www.fftw.org/fftw-3.3.4.tar.gz
tar xf fftw-3.3.4.tar.gz
cd fftw-3.3.4
CFLAGS="-I/foo/bar" ./configure --prefix=/tmp   # We aren't going to run 'make install',
                                                # so the --prefix is unimportant.

make -j4
```

Now let's inspect the compiled output.  Notice that the silly `-I/foo/bar` flag ended up in the binary itself!

```bash
$ strings .libs/libfftw3.a | grep gcc
gcc -I/foo/bar
```

For technical reasons not worth mentioning here (related to a package management tool), I would like to prevent that, or at least understand why it is happening, and if it is important.

BTW: This seems to happen on both Linux and OS X, for both shared and static libraries.

Comment: No reproducible [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/522a2aa00b1fa5d5). Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @n.m. OK, I've edited to question to provide a real-world example (fftw).  You can copy+paste those commands on your own machine, which should only take about 30 seconds to run.

Comment: Study the generated `Makefile`-s

Comment: Unfortunately, it's a little hard to make any sense of them.

Comment: `fgrep 'gcc -I/foo/bar' config.h`

Comment: @n.m. Thanks! Looks like `FFTW_CC` is getting built into the binary via `api/version.c`.  I had thought that somehow autotools or make was doing this out-of-the-box.  But it appears that the fftw authors wrote this into the library themselves.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this was specific to `fftw`.  Thanks to @n.m. for helping me see that.

The fftw sources have a line like the following.  (Simplifying here.)

```c
// api/version.c
const char fftwf_cc[] = FFTW_CC;
```

And via its configure/make scripts, fftw uses something like the following build command (again, drastically simplifying here).

```sh
gcc -I/foo/bar -DFFTW_CC='"gcc -I/foo/bar"' -c api/version.c
```

... so no wonder it ends up getting compiled into the library.